# Ava unit tests failing with TypeScript ("SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier")

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, ava

I'm learning TypeScript and I created a TypeScript React app with `create-react-app`.  It uses a separate TypeScript file, `logic.ts`, which in turn imports a JSON file

```
import pastaData from './data/users-pasta.json'

 const ParsedUserData  = pastaData.map(data => ({name: data.name, gender:data.gender,favorites: data.favorites}));

export const getPastaData = () => ParsedUserData;
```

It works fine.  But when I run my Ava test (which for the moment does nothing)

```
const {getPastaData} = require( '../src/logic.ts')

describe("A suite", function() {
  it("contains spec with an expectation", function() {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

I get the following error

> ```
> /src/logic.ts:1
> (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import pastaData from './data/users-pasta.json';
> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
> ```

It's complaining about the 'pastaData' import here.

I set up Ava to work with Typescript (from package.json)

```
{

  "ava": {
    "compileEnhancements": false,
    "extensions": [
      "ts"
    ],
    "require": [
      "ts-node/register"
    ]
  }
}
```

And have now been trying to get `Ava-ts` to work.  Same problem.

I think it's an issue with `ts-node` but changing all the linked files to 'require' is proving problematic (and TypeScript starts complaining).  Is there a way to get this to work with 'ES-6' 'imports'?  Or is there something else I'm missing entirely?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AVA (with TypeScript setup) compiles the TypeScript code back to JavaScript before execution.

And NodeJS does not support esm syntax unless you are doing `*.mjs`.

So you have to set your "module" to "commonjs" in your `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```